# Find top 3 highest values across 3 columns row-wise pandas

Tags: pandas

I have four columns of values consisting of the looking times to a right/left/upper/lower positioned image. Another column shows the position of the image which was chosen (decision_resp). I created a new column showing the looking time of the chosen image. Now I want to create 3 more columns showing the looking times of the not chosen images sorted by highest looking time (top1), second highest looking time (toop2) and third highest looking time (top 3). The looking time of the chosen image has to be excluded.

These are the columns I have:

```
 lookRight_t  lookLeft_t  lookUp_t  lookDown_t decision_resp  chosen_img_et
0     1.291667    1.325000  3.025000    1.141667            up       3.025000
1     0.000000    0.000000  1.125000    3.150000          down       3.150000
2     0.000000    0.000000  3.508333    2.275000            up       3.508333
3     3.700000    1.950000  0.000000    0.000000         right       3.700000
4     2.633333    1.316667  1.341667    0.000000         right       2.633333
5     1.766667    1.333333  0.825000    2.208333          down       2.208333
6     0.000000    0.000000  1.108333    5.283333          down       5.283333
```

My approach was:

```
# create new column for looking time of chosen image
trials.loc[trials['decision_resp']=='right','chosen_img_et'] = trials['lookRight_t']
trials.loc[trials['decision_resp']=='left','chosen_img_et'] = trials['lookLeft_t']
trials.loc[trials['decision_resp']=='down','chosen_img_et'] = trials['lookDown_t']
trials.loc[trials['decision_resp']=='up','chosen_img_et'] = trials['lookUp_t']

# here I got stuck        
trials.loc[trials['decision_resp']=='right', 3 new columns (top1/2/3)] = trials[['lookLeft_t', 'lookDown_t', 'lookUp_t']].find max values and put it in order
trials.loc[trials['decision_resp']=='left', 3 new columns (top1/2/3)] = trials[['lookRight_t', 'lookDown_t', 'lookUp_t']].find max values and put it in order
trials.loc[trials['decision_resp']=='down', 3 new columns (top1/2/3)] = trials[['lookLeft_t', 'lookRight_t', 'lookUp_t']].find max values and put it in order
trials.loc[trials['decision_resp']=='up', 3 new columns (top1/2/3)] = trials[['lookLeft_t', 'lookDown_t', 'lookRight_t']].find max values and put it in order
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: There are easier ways to do most of these steps~ `idxmax`, `max`, `nlargest` etc... see my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

First you can use [Looking up](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels) solution for new column `chosen_img_et`

You can sorting selected columns by [`numpy.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) and then use indexing for top3 rows without selected value, so is compared columns names by column `decision_resp` with broadcasting and set missing values by mask by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
cols = ['lookRight_t','lookLeft_t','lookUp_t','lookDown_t']
#replace substrings for match column decision_resp
look = [x.replace('look','').replace('_t','').lower() for x in cols]

new = [f'top{x+1}' for x in range(3)]

#lookup
idx1, cols1 = pd.factorize(trials['decision_resp'])
trials['chosen_img_et'] = (trials[cols].set_axis(look, axis=1)
                                       .reindex(cols1, axis=1)
                                       .to_numpy()[np.arange(len(trials)), idx1])

mask = np.array(look) == trials['decision_resp'].to_numpy()[:, None]

#np.sort sorting by default descending, 
#so for ascending order use -1 in indexing and 2 is for remove first only NaN column
trials[new] = np.sort(trials[cols].mask(mask), axis=1)[:, 2::-1]
```

---

```
print (trials)
   lookRight_t  lookLeft_t  lookUp_t  lookDown_t decision_resp  chosen_img_et  \
0     1.291667    1.325000  3.025000    1.141667            up       3.025000   
1     0.000000    0.000000  1.125000    3.150000          down       3.150000   
2     0.000000    0.000000  3.508333    2.275000            up       3.508333   
3     3.700000    1.950000  0.000000    0.000000         right       3.700000   
4     2.633333    1.316667  1.341667    0.000000         right       2.633333   
5     1.766667    1.333333  0.825000    2.208333          down       2.208333   
6     0.000000    0.000000  1.108333    5.283333          down       5.283333   

       top1      top2      top3  
0  1.325000  1.291667  1.141667  
1  1.125000  0.000000  0.000000  
2  2.275000  0.000000  0.000000  
3  1.950000  0.000000  0.000000  
4  1.341667  1.316667  0.000000  
5  1.766667  1.333333  0.825000  
6  1.108333  0.000000  0.000000
```

**Details**:

```
print (trials[cols].mask(mask))
   lookRight_t  lookLeft_t  lookUp_t  lookDown_t
0     1.291667    1.325000       NaN    1.141667
1     0.000000    0.000000  1.125000         NaN
2     0.000000    0.000000       NaN    2.275000
3          NaN    1.950000  0.000000    0.000000
4          NaN    1.316667  1.341667    0.000000
5     1.766667    1.333333  0.825000         NaN
6     0.000000    0.000000  1.108333         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

- Find the max column name and extract the direction from it.
- Find the max for each row.
- Find the remaining 3 values and sort them as desired.
- Concat the results together.

  - Renameing columns as I go.

```
decision_resp = df.idxmax(axis=1).str.extract('look(\w*)_t', expand=False)
decision_resp.rename('decision_resp', inplace=True)

chosen_img_et = df.max(axis=1, numeric_only=True)
chosen_img_et.rename('chosen_img_et', inplace=True)

top3 = df.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(4).sort_values(ascending=False, ignore_index=True)[1:], axis=1)
top3.columns = ['top1', 'top2', 'top3']

df = pd.concat([df, decision_resp, chosen_img_et, top3], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   lookRight_t  lookLeft_t  lookUp_t  lookDown_t decision_resp  chosen_img_et  \
0     1.291667    1.325000  3.025000    1.141667            Up       3.025000   
1     0.000000    0.000000  1.125000    3.150000          Down       3.150000   
2     0.000000    0.000000  3.508333    2.275000            Up       3.508333   
3     3.700000    1.950000  0.000000    0.000000         Right       3.700000   
4     2.633333    1.316667  1.341667    0.000000         Right       2.633333   
5     1.766667    1.333333  0.825000    2.208333          Down       2.208333   
6     0.000000    0.000000  1.108333    5.283333          Down       5.283333   

       top1      top2      top3  
0  1.325000  1.291667  1.141667  
1  1.125000  0.000000  0.000000  
2  2.275000  0.000000  0.000000  
3  1.950000  0.000000  0.000000  
4  1.341667  1.316667  0.000000  
5  1.766667  1.333333  0.825000  
6  1.108333  0.000000  0.000000
```

Other way, addressing jezrael's concerns:

```
col_list = ['lookRight_t', 'lookLeft_t', 'lookUp_t', 'lookDown_t']
idx, cols = pd.factorize('look' + df['decision_resp'].str.title() + '_t')
df['chosen_img_et'] = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
mask = np.array(col_list) == df['decision_resp'].to_numpy()[:, None]
df[[f'top{x+1}' for x in range(3)]] = np.sort(df[col_list].mask(mask), axis=1)[:, 2::-1]
```

Output:

```
   lookRight_t  lookLeft_t  lookUp_t  lookDown_t decision_resp  chosen_img_et  \
0     1.291667    1.325000  3.025000    1.141667            up       3.025000   
1     0.000000    0.000000  1.125000    3.150000          down       3.150000   
2     0.000000    0.000000  3.508333    2.275000            up       3.508333   
3     3.700000    1.950000  0.000000    0.000000         right       3.700000   
4     2.633333    1.316667  1.341667    0.000000         right       2.633333   
5     1.766667    1.333333  0.825000    2.208333          down       2.208333   
6     0.000000    0.000000  1.108333    5.283333          down       5.283333   

       top1      top2      top3  
0  1.325000  1.291667  1.141667  
1  1.125000  0.000000  0.000000  
2  2.275000  0.000000  0.000000  
3  1.950000  0.000000  0.000000  
4  1.341667  1.316667  0.000000  
5  1.766667  1.333333  0.825000  
6  1.108333  0.000000  0.000000
```

Comment: I think problem of solution is for top3 remove largest value, not by column `decision_resp`. try change first `Up` to `Down` and you can get wrong ouput. Try compare with my solution with correct ouput.

Comment: @jezrael We have the same exact output... `decision_resp` is *derived* from the first four columns, not assigned. It's never going to change.

Comment: hmmm, if check question `Another column shows the position of the image which was chosen (decision_resp)`. So it means I can choose any value. So how you know OP need max value and never another?

Comment: @jezrael Looking at it again, it's probable that you're correct, but my suspicion is that OP is just over-complicating things. The fact that the chosen one is always the highest value is too much of a coincidence to ignore.  I'll add a separate solution that addresses your way.

Comment: @jezrael How do those changes look?

Comment: @jezrael I was curious, so I figured out how yours worked, and made it even faster :) `730 µs ± 20.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)` vs `817 µs ± 14.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)`

Comment: So you change small part of my solution and post? Why?

Comment: Because I fully expected you to take my modifications and apply them to your answer, and then I'd remove the overlap. I still believe my discussion of `idxmax` and `nlargest` is valuable, even if it may not apply directly to OPs question.

Comment: I think not necessary, in future you can avoid it. Happy coding.